# Using ElaasticSearch script in the Grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I’m going to use this ElasticSearch query in the Grafana:

[image]

But the result in Grafana is something like this:

[image]

How can I remove the **field** part in the Grfafana?

Comment: Why don't you simply declare the `load-value` field as `double` in your mapping instead of resorting to scripting just for that?

Comment: It needs a huge reindexing process.

Comment: If you're using time-based indices, you should fix the mapping for the future indices to be created

Comment: I don't use a new time-based index, I just try to visualize data in current indices.

Comment: I would strongly encourage to use proper mapping, it's a better approach in a long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manipulated the native ElasticSearch data source plugin. Now if the field does not have value and the script has, It will only use the script in an inline tag.

[image]

The result is something like this:

“aggs”:{“3”:{“sum”:***{“script”:{“inline”:“Double.parseDouble(doc[‘load-value’].value)”}}***}}